# Laravel 5.3: results only loop when going to /index not to the root of the site

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I fight with a problem. I have little experience with Laravel, but fortunately I learn things quickly in. But unfortunately I'm still having a problem where I can not get out. I have created a Gist on Github for people who want to see my code.

**The problem is as follows:**

- When I go to mywebsite.com/index then I have no problems and the last threads will show from the database.
- But when I'm just going to mywebsite.com without / index then I get the following error:

> ErrorException in e88feb49b77f48fdc3e88c1287897bff1ddb3785.php line 138:
>   Undefined variable: threads (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\index.blade.php)
>
> ErrorException in e88feb49b77f48fdc3e88c1287897bff1ddb3785.php line 138:
>   Undefined variable: threads

https://gist.github.com/Sygun/3e5d9b8f0c80ed96bfd60057a40bad2f

Comment: It is frowned upon in Stack Overflow to include code via a link. You should edit your post to include the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web routes you have that:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

so laravel returns `index.blade.php` view, with no passed data.

change this to:

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
```

and the problem is solved.

---

Additionally you may want to remove this line. It is unnecessary I think, but maybe you need this for another future functionality.

```
Route::get('/index', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
```